# How to initialize a dynamically sized array in C++11 standard?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initialization, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is my piece of code.

```
    int** n;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        int size;
        cin >> size;
        int* n[i] = new int[size]; //line 13
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j){
            cin >> n[i][j];
        }
    }
```

This is the error that pops up during compilation.

> solution.cc: In function 'int main()':
>
> solution.cc:13:33: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
>
> int* n[i] = new int[size];

I realise that this can be done using vectors since they are so much better at handling memory dynamically. But I am not allowed to use vectors for this challenge. The only header I am allowed to use is "iostream".

I read that, in C++11, the syntax has been modified for new:

```
    p = new T [N] {initializer1, ..., initializerN};
```

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_and_delete_(C%2B%2B)#Overview

But my code still produces the same error for similar variants.

Is there a way to bypass the initialization error totally? If not, assume that the values are initialized to, preferably, the same value.

Comment: `n[i] = new int[size];` will get you past compiler errors. However, `n` is an uninitialized pointer and you are trying to dereference it, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Igor - add this as an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe (IMHO) you are not looking to the real problem.

You have declared a double pointer:

```
int** n;
```

Then you forget to allocate memory for the array of pointers, something like:

```
n = new int*[N]
```

This step is necessary before you can allocate memory for each pointer of your array (of pointers).

Moreover, I believe that your line should be:

```
n[i] = new int[size]
```

else you are redeclaring the type of n+i.

Answer (score 6):

This should solve your problem.

```
int** n = new int*[N];

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    n[i] = new int[size];

    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j){
        cin >> n[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a favor and stop using raw pointers. Use `std::vector` in place of raw arrays whenever possible - something along these lines:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> n(N);
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    n[i].resize(size);
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j){
        cin >> n[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: > I realise that this can be done using vectors since they are so much better at handling memory dynamically. But I am not allowed to use vectors for this challenge.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer does nothing to explain what is actually wrong with the OP's code. As such, I don't think it's helpful to anyone trying to learn C/C++.